Runtime Mapped Types
I want to map custom type classes and expect them to work seemlessly with TypeScript's Mapped Types.
The issue is that when I use a callback, the result will be expanded(?) to a union, which I don't want.
I believe the code speaks for itself
const any = (any?: any) => any;

// CONSTRAINTS

namespace Constraint {
  export type OBJ = { [K: string]: ANY };

  export type OPT = ANY;

  // @ts-ignore // I know how to fix this, but please ignore for now! Thank you :)
  export type ANY = Str | Num | Obj<OBJ> | Opt<ANY>;
}

// TYPES

type Nested<T extends { nested: unknown }> = T['nested'];

type Opt<T extends Constraint.OPT> = OPT<T>;

type Str = STR;

type Num = NUM;

type Obj<T extends Constraint.OBJ> = OBJ<T>;

// CLASSES

class OPT<T extends Constraint.OPT> {
  opt: undefined;

  constructor(public nested: T) {}
}

class OBJ<T extends Constraint.OBJ> {
  obj: undefined;

  public map<R extends Constraint.ANY>(
    cb: (value: Nested<this>[keyof Nested<this>]) => R
  ): Obj<{
    [K in keyof Nested<this>]: R;
  }> {
    return any(cb);
  }

  constructor(public nested: T) {}
}

class STR {
  str: undefined;
}
class NUM {
  num: undefined;
}

// FUNCTIONS

const Opt = <T extends Constraint.OPT>(nested: T): Opt<T> => new OPT<T>(nested);

const Obj = <T extends Constraint.OBJ>(nested: T): Obj<T> => new OBJ<T>(nested);

const Str = (): Str => new STR();

const Num = (): Num => new NUM();

// USE

const example = Obj({
  one: Str(),
  two: Num(),
});

export const result = example.map((value) => Opt(value)); // => See below:

I get this:
Obj<{
    one: Opt<STR | NUM>;
    two: Opt<STR | NUM>;
}>

But I really just want this:
Obj<{
    one: Opt<STR>;
    two: Opt<NUM>;
}>

Playground
Would I need HKTs (Higher-Kinded Types) for this, as described here, or can I solve it another way?

• "I believe the code speaks for itself" I think you could almost certainly reduce this to a [mre] without the complexity; Nested<this> which maps to this["nested"] and... class names in all caps?  It's a slog. And definitely without anything like "please ignore this" because it still places cognitive burden on people you're asking to help.

(see prev comment) • I don't think you can do this with current TS, at least without truly bizarre operations.  It's fundamentally the same problem as this question; the description of what cb actually is in general is too complex for TS to infer, and pretty ugly for you to annotate. You could write it this way (playground) if you're willing to give up on inference and just write out pairs of IO types. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?


The code does speak better for itself, than me explaining it, yes.
Nested reduces complexity and improves readability, as it is used several times.
class names are all caps to avoid naming conflicts.
@ts-ignore is perfectly valid TS, and is needed in the example as the minimal code is not the whole codebase.
The question is minimal to my usecase.
I think the issue is you being pedantic and not the code being complex.
Your solution seems overengineered, and I did find a better solution.
Thanks for your answer.


I will admit to being pedantic, but given that the only person here yet who understands your code and what it’s supposed to do is you, I don’t think you can claim that the example isn’t too complex. It’s great you were able to simulate HKT’s in a way you found acceptable! I wish TS had a lightweight HKT solution native to the language so people didn’t have to roll their own.

Fair enough. I could have certainly asked a more generic question. Seeing the issue has been open for a decade isn't promising, but I hope so as well.

Luckily, I did not give up, and found a great solution.
By providing the desired wrapped return type either as generic or as value, I could simulate HKTs.
The idea is to first find the unique symbol inside the wanted return type, and then replacing it with the given type at the given index (or key).
Like this:
const US: unique symbol = Symbol('US');

type US = typeof US;

type Recurse<V, T> = V extends US
  ? T
  : V extends Obj<infer O>
  ? Obj<{ [K in keyof O]: Recurse<O[K], T> }>
  : V extends Opt<infer O>
  ? Opt<Recurse<O, T>>
  : V extends object
  ? { [K in keyof V]: Recurse<V[K], T> }
  : never;

Now to make the callback typesafe I have to replace the US with all possible value types of Nested<this>.
For that I have a very similar looking utility type:
type ReplaceValue<V, T> = V extends US
  ? T
  : V extends Obj<infer O>
  ? Obj<{ [K in keyof O]: ReplaceValue<O[K], T> }>
  : V extends Opt<infer O>
  ? Opt<ReplaceValue<O, T>>
  : V extends object
  ? { [K in keyof V]: ReplaceValue<V[K], T> }
  : never;

Finally, I have two utilities to "compute" and "simplify" the result:
// You can not name it `Magic` if you don't like it.
type Magic<V, T extends Obj<any>> = Obj<{
  [K in keyof Nested<T>]: Recurse<V, Nested<T>[K]>;
}>;

type Simple<T> = T extends Obj<infer V> ? Obj<V> : never;

The final map function/-s look/-s like this:
  public map<R extends Constraint.ANY>(
    cb: <N extends Nested<this>, K extends keyof N>(value: N[K]) => ReplaceValue<R, N[K]>
  ): Simple<Magic<R, this>> {
    return any(cb);
  }

  public mapNoGeneric<R extends Constraint.ANY>(
    expected: R,
    cb: <N extends Nested<this>, K extends keyof N>(value: N[K]) => ReplaceValue<R, N[K]>
  ): Simple<Magic<R, this>> {
    return any(cb);
  }

And are used like this
export const result = example.map<Opt<US>>((value) => Opt(value));

export const result2 = example.mapNoGeneric(Opt(US), (value) => Opt(value)); // could probably even be done without the callback!

Finally the whole code in a Playground.
